# Ios-Afnetworking multiple download using selector method

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

Handle single download  via afnetworking is good my question is that how handle multiple click on different button then it call this method then process break previous.

it is bcoz suppose several button hit at time then it confuse to download. how handle multiple download in selector method,if in array of batch download then it's easy but through which how .

```
-(void)downloadimagefromserver:(UIButton *)sender
{
 int index =(int) sender.tag;
 historyclass *class1 = [messages objectAtIndex:index];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:arrayOfStringsfinal[1]]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
       NSLog(@"success");




} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];


    [operation start];
}
```